# lookup encrypted text by clear text without decryption

Tags: data-privacy, aes-gcm, searchable-encryption, secure-index

I've implemented vouchers module in my web project where I use it to generate redeem get etc... vouchers.

since voucher codes are considered sensitive, I've considered to encrypt them using AES-GCM.

but how can I query clear voucher code to encrypted one to check voucher validity in order to redeem later?

I've thought of these two solutions

1. I am thinking to make like a MD5 for the clear code to live in the
   document, in order to match it with clear code queries?
2. Reversed distribute, where to give the user encrypted voucher codes, and store the clear voucher codes on the DB, 
   when a query is applied to redeem a voucher system decrypt code applied with secret key and iv and looks for a match?

Does those approaches carries less performance overhead than decrypting whole data?, is it safe to consider one of them.

**Audience of threats**

1. system admins
2. attackers
3. DB data breach

Comment: I advise you keep the data under AES-GCM, and in another column store the hashes of the vouchers codes with a `secure` hash function. With negligible probability, you will get a collison.  However, your threats are very broad.

Comment: Similar to what @kelalaka says, some form of one-way hash should be sufficient, especially with something modern (not MD5, but SHA2 or something).  If you're worried about sysadmins, though, I'd be more concerned about them adding new records, not discovering existing ones - at which point you need some sort of HSM (hardware security module) that stores/uses a secret for all the hashing and encrypting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query with `SELECT`

- AES with `ECB` mode can be used as long as the vouchers codes are unique. ECB mode gives you the same results when the key and plaintext are same.
- Another solution is continuing to use AES-GCM to save your vouchers codes. To have the equality on the `SELECT` statement, use a secure hash function e.g. choose from the SHA3 family. With negligible probability, you will have a collision. If you have a collision store the values, you will be famous. In any case, you will decrypt the AES-GSM after the match of the hash values.

### Attacks

As I said in the comment you attack is very broad; I will give answer for single cases;

1. **System admins:** If you don't trust them, this is a serious issue. They can query everything, even you deploy an HSM. They can insert, delete, etc. Keeping a query log of the Database may help you investigate. Also, there are works as [RSA Beehive's](http://www.arijuels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/YOOL-13.pdf) that can detect the behavioral change of the users of the system that will can block action. They claimed that "*we can prevent the Snowden.*"
2. **Attackers:** For the database attack, see the next. If the attacker access the application servers they will be same as a malicious system administrator, probably, a short time.
3. **DB data breach**: Since the clear vouchers are not in the database, We expect that by the collision-free and the security of AES-GCM the database will be untouched. However, if the database attacker is also an active attacker, you may need some integrity into your rows and even some chaining link for the columns. A simple one as in blow;

```
r_i  = |data_1|... |data_k| h_i   = hash(data_1,...,data_k)| sign(h)|
r_i+1 =|data_1|....|data_k| h_i+1 = hash(data_1,...,data_k)| sign(h_i+1||h_i|)|
```

Comment: I will use sha-256 since it generates same sha, is it ok to use sha's for matching queries, I am a total newbie in crypto, i will create hashed index in the db to match queries aganset

Comment: Each SHA generates different values. SHA-256 generates 256-bit hash value.